# Opencv: train cascade image reader

Tags: opencv, training-data

i try to training a classifier, i have create a file .vec whit create sample and it's ok.

```
Info file name: C:\OpenCV\positive.txt
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: C:\OpenCV\sample.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 20
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 50
Height: 50
Create training samples from images collection...
Done. Created 20 samples
```

and now use training.bat, this is the file:

```
C:\OpenCV\opencv-2_4\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data classifier -vec "C:\OpenCV\samples.vec" -bg "C:\OpenCV\negative.txt" -npos 20 -nneg 16 -numStages 4 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAllarmRate 0.5 -w 74 -h 100 -mode ALL -precalcvalBuffSize 256 -precalcdxBufSize 256
```

But when i call training.bat in dos give me this error:

```
Image reader can not be created from -vec C:\OpenCV\samples.vec and -bg C:\OpenCV\negative.txt.
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It generally pops when the files do not exist in the directory you are calling, make sure you wrote the file name and path correctly, and make sure the vector file you are calling has the ".vec" extension.